# NodeJs para aplicações em tempo real

Tags: node.js, mongodb, angular

Recentemente, com a chegada de Angular2 beta, tenho buscado mais informações a respeito de aplicações em tempo real.

Atualmente trabalho com `AngularJs` (1.x) no `front-end` com servidor apache em `MySql` & `Php` para o `backend`, o que não está nada fácil para esse tipo de aplicação.

Encontrei alguns materiais e já fiz alguns projetos testes básicos utilizando `Angular2` e `Firebase`. Porém `Firebase`, apesar de ser excelente e simplificar BASTANTE o trabalho, não supre a necessidade quando necessito de algo mais bem estruturado e elaborado, como um e-commerce, carteira de clientes, etc..

Lendo mais a respeito disso, ou mais especificamente MEAN, estou achando bem interessante a proposta de utilizar esse conjunto. Mas antes de decidir mudar para um ou outro, gostaria de entender mais sobre esse cenário.

Ao contrário do `Firebase`, que já possui funções de comunicações entre cliente e servidor automatizadas, caso utilize um servidor em `NodeJs` necessitaria utilizar alguma ferramenta de `WebSocket`, como o [socketo.io](http://socket.io/), então com isso gostaria de tirar algumas dúvidas:

- Ao utilizar minha aplicação com `Angular2` em front-end e `NodeJs` backend, qual seria um bom banco de dados para utilizar em conjunto? `MySql`ou `MongoDb` são as as opções mais fortes que tenho no momento. O primeiro por ser o que atualmente trabalho e o segundo por parecer semelhante e já estar em conjunto com o modelo MEAN. Mas se houver outra opção melhor, será bem vinda também. A única requisição é ter um bom desempenho em real-time app.
- Caso eu escolha pela utilização de `NodeJs` é necessário utilizar algum tipo de hospedagem específica? Ou essas mais comuns que existem no mercado hoje já suprem? Como a hospedagem Uol, Weblink (usada atualmente), Locaweb, etc..

Caso tenham mais observações a cerca do assunto, por favor, comentem, pois estou nesse impasse de mudança de linguagem de backend e gostaria de saber mais antes de tomar a decisão. Obrigado.

Comment: Celsom, lanças perguntas interessantes aqui. Contudo acho que esta pergunta é ampla demais. Somente a pergunta "diferênças JSON - MongoDB vs Table - MySql" é grande demais para estar junto de outras. De resto posso dizer que uso Node.js + MySql com o módulo [node.mysql](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql) e funciona bem, outros usam MongoDB. Cada vez há mais alojamentos a disponibilizar Node.js. Também podes ter um VPS e configurar o Node manualmente com NginX por exemplo... Separa algumas das perguntas aqui em perguntas separadas e vai ser interessante seguir.

Comment: @Sergio a sim perfeito! Realmente, lendo com mais calma depois notei que ficou meio abrangente... Tentei simplificar agora e deixar mais objetivo. Espero que tenha conseguido, obrigado pela dica.